# Maven can't download a dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have imported a project from GitHub as maven project. When I try to build, maven couldn't download a .jar. I tried to enter to the link of the jar and it seems to be impossible to download it, the server is too slow.
I searched in pom files to change the link of the jar but not found !!!
The project is constructed of a parent folder and 7 sub-projects

This is the link where maven tries to download 
http://maven.petalslink.com/others/net/sf/saxon/saxonhe/9.2.0.6/

I want to override it with this one for example
https://maven.repository.redhat.com/nexus/content/groups/product-ga/net/sourceforge/saxon/saxonhe/9.2.1.5/

PS: it is my first time working with maven

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

To control where Maven downloads dependencies from, you should set the **repositories** part of Maven's [settings.xml](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html).

Comment: I have added the repository and deleted the old one, he is trying to download saxonhe 9.2.0.6 version which in not available in the new repository. So I think somewhere there is a version precised of saxonhe. I made a search in the whole project of saxonhe NOT found !!!

Comment: The version in defined in the dependency section in the pom.xml file. You should set it there.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a `repositories` or `distributionManagement` section in your `pom.xml`, you can replace the slow repository URL with the one you want in the relevant `repository` element. Make sure though that the new repository contains *all* the artifacts that you needed to download from the original one.